# Read data from multiple rows PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, extract

I have a database to keep track of the services clients have. But need to be able to find all the services (on different rows) and display them in an HTML table.
 
**i.e.**

```
Service     Company         Status
-------------------------------------
Service 1   Company 1       Complete
Service 2   Company 2       Pending
Service 3   Company 1       Complete
```

I need to extract the service and status for each entry for Company 1 and display it in an HTML table. How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Service</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT Service, Status FROM services WHERE Company='Company 1'");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          //  ^ must be a single '=' !!!!
      echo '<tr><td>' . $row["Service"] . '</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $row["Status"] . '</td></tr>';
  } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: @Query good point; I was a total noob when I wrote the answer.